# Center vertically when the height of element is unknown

Tags: html, css

I want to center vertically text, when the elements height is unknown?

**html**

```
<div class="table">
  <div class="table-resp">

    <div class="second-row">
      <div class="col-md-5">
          <div class="left-col-text">
            Center vertically
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-7">
        <div class="right-col-text">
          <div class="example">Ex1</div>
          <div class="example">Ex2</div>
          <div class="example">Ex3</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */
.table{
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 70px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 35px;
}

.table-resp{
    border: 1px solid green;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.text1{
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}

.second-row{
    line-height: 30px;
    clear: left;
    min-height: 30px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.left-col-text{
    height: 100%;  
}
```

Elements "Ex1, Ex2" count is unknown, so, if there are more of those, obviously, the table row will get bigger in height. I need some solution, that would be responsive to this also...

```
https://www.codeply.com/go/bp/4ZEUS7Q7lm
```

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `row-ht-eq` class to row `<div class="second-row">`

CSS:

```
.row-ht-eq {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Note: Flex is only an option if you only need to support current browsers. See: [Can I use Flex?](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex)

Answer (score 0):

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

Also you can play with:

```
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** Use `span` Element as helper.

**Html:**

```
<div class="col-md-5">
          <span class="helper"></span>
          <div class="left-col-text">
            Center vertically
          </div>
</div>
```

**Css:**

```
.helper {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**Full Code:**

```css
.table{
 text-align: center;
    padding-top: 70px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 35px;
}

.table-resp{
    border: 1px solid green;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.text1{
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}

.second-row{
    line-height: 30px;
    clear: left;
    min-height: 30px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.left-col-text{
    height: 100%;  
}

.helper {
 display: inline-block;
 height: 100%;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="table">
  <div class="table-resp">

    <div class="second-row">
      <div class="col-md-5">
          <span class="helper"></span>
          <div class="left-col-text">
            Center vertically
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-7">
        <div class="right-col-text">
          <div class="example">Ex1</div>
          <div class="example">Ex2</div>
          <div class="example">Ex3</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your text class to:

```
.left-col-text {
   margin:0 auto;
}
```

This will automatically decide equal distance from top to bottom.